# Is there a WordPress plugin or a php code to insert a table that user can manipulate the data in it

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Right now I am using the ultimate member plugin to register users. But the company asked me to change the form and allow users to insert their education qualifications in a table when registering. Users need to have a button that has the ability to insert more rows (If they have more qualifications).
As far as I know, I can't use the Ultimate Member plugin for that. I searched for many table plugins but didn't find anything that can do this task. I once had done this using code. But I don't know how to apply it to this registration form. If anyone can figure out a way to embed the code to Ultimate member (to save that table data) or any plugin that can do this, please let me know soon as possible.

**Updated Question**

I have tried that shortcode and got confused as it ruined the page. Now I'm trying a PHP method to solve this problem.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Well you have many options to solve this problem. What you are actually looking for is [Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/).

> WordPress has the ability to allow post authors to assign custom fields to a post. This arbitrary extra information is known as metadata.

Now, custom fields can be created in 2 ways.

1. Either you write php code in a plugin/theme
2. Or you you install plugin which helps you build custom fields.

What you are actually looking for is to create **Repeatable Field Groups**. These are the field which can be replicated. As many as you want.

Some plugins which provide facility to add them in no particular order are:

- [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) - Repeater Field : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/
- [Toolset](https://toolset.com/) - Repetable Field Group : https://toolset.com/course-lesson/creating-and-displaying-repeatable-field-groups/
- [Metabox](https://metabox.io) - Meta Box Group : https://metabox.io/plugins/meta-box-group/

They all will give you ability to create repeater fields.
Repeater field can be made for both users and posts or [Custom Post Types](https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-types/#custom-post-types)(CPT). You need them for Users. I am not sure which one of them allows you to create repeater field for Users but you can check on there website.

> PS : These are all paid plugins. (They may have free version of them but repeater field comes with PRO).

Once you have created a field for users you can use that field in your registration form.

### UPDATED ANSWER

As the question author wants to add the field using PHP, the field can be added as so.

After looking at [all the hooks](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1324-hooks-list) available to the user by UM (Ultimate Member) plugin. I found two hook that can be used to add fields and save in the backend.

1. [`um_after_form`](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1017-umafterform) : Some actions after register form fields.

```php
add_action( 'um_after_form', 'my_after_form', 10, 1 );
function my_after_form( $args ) {
    // add your repetable fields here.
}
```

2. [`um_after_save_registration_details`](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1026-umaftersaveregistrationdetails) : Action on user registration after save details. This runs after the form is submited and user is registered. Use this to save data inside the user database.

```php
add_action( 'um_after_save_registration_details', 'my_after_save_registration_details', 10, 2 );
function my_after_save_registration_details( $user_id, $submitted ) {
    // Save field here.
    // You have user_id and submitted data, do your thing here.
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to solve this problem with PHP code. I made a shortcode with a repeatable function. But now trying to embed it with ultimate member

Comment: @JanithaTharaka. I would advice you to edit your question and update it with the new PHP code you added. Also adding shortcode won't help you with field addition at Ultimate memeber plugin registration. What you need to do is use that PHP code, code to hook into the registration form. I have updated my answer according to your new findings. Pls check.

Comment: yes sir. I have tried that shortcode and got confused as it ruined the page. I will try this. Thank you @Bhanu